# 'crumb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: flutter

While I am trying to run flutter app and when I hit flutter run I am getting this error.

```
'crumb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using window maybe try this
go to ***system environment*** and ***add*** to system path name as ***`path`*** and  the value :

```
C:\Windows\System32;flutter bin path e.g D:\flutter\bin
```

then add to the `path` you've created the **shell command path** so you  won't face any problem

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

sorry for my english :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the  2 solutions which will work for sure

solution 1:
As @Ali said add it to the environmental variables properly and save it

Solution 2:
**Go to flutter installation folder and inside flutter/bin edit the flutter.bat file using a text editor and remove the line (20) that says:**

```
IF EXIST "%mingit_path%" SET PATH=%PATH%;%mingit_path%
```

**The code should look like this on those lines**:

```
REM If available, add location of bundled mingit to PATH 
SET mingit_path=%FLUTTER_ROOT%\bin\mingit\cmd
```

**Save and Run flutter doctor and everything should work fine.**

Note for opening the bat file you can use your text editor or use notepad ++